# How do I use "Fetch"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
class Fetch {
  async getCurrent(input) {
    const apiKey = "my_api_key";

    // make request to url

    const response = await fetch(
      `https:/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&appid=${apiKey}`
    );

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Above is a snippet of code, can someone point me to the direction of the error?

Comment: I am only just learning this and do not understand why there is an issue. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You are missing `/` in `https:/` (should be `https://`), but that won't cause that error. How are you executing this code? It should work fine in any decent up-to-date browser.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include a [mre]. This code only defines a class and does nothing else. If this is in [tag:node.js], then 1. you forgot to include the tag and 2. you forgot to Google [“node.js fetch”](//google.com/search?q=node.js+fetch).

Comment: here you can see how i've used openweather to make a widget https://github.com/justoverclockl/geo-weather/blob/main/js/src/forum/GeoWeather.js

Comment: thanks for the help, however I'm not running the code in node.js

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. The error message is telling you that `fetch` isn’t a function. So, what is it? What caused it to not be a function? Create a [mre]. Are you doing `const fetch = new Fetch()`?

Comment: yeah I have const fetch = new Fetch() in my app.js file

Comment: As I thought. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. Problem can be in that how you call function.

You need to create an object, outside the class and call the function.

```
let f = new Fetch();
f.getCurrent("Kiev");
```

You can`t use variable name *fetch* because this name is reserved.

Comment: I have a fetch.js file, and an app.js file, on the app.js I have: 'const fetch = new Fetch();'

Comment: You need to import your fetch.js in your html file also app.js, then in app.js just use this `code const f= new Fetch(); f.getCurrent("Kiev");` Because fetch is reserve name

Comment: yeah they are both imported already il try making the change on my app.js, what does reverse name mean if you dont mind me asking? im still a novice haha

Comment: Ive tried it and the issue has been solved thanks for your help much appreciated

Comment: In JS we have reserved words you cannot use as variables, labels, or function names. Because that`s name of default functions etс. Here you can check this words [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are running this code in Node.js, right?

If it's in the browser, you shouldn't have any issue since the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API is implemented in the browser.

**If you are running in Node.js** you can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) which is a great implementation of `fetch` in Node.js.